# Synthetic Control method: how to select V matrix?

Tags: econometrics, inference

I am learning Synthetic Control method and reading paper."Synthetic Control Methods for Comparative Case Studies: Estimating the Effect of California’s Tobacco Control Program" 
We need to minimize the formula below to find the weight W. But there is also a V matrix in this equation. How could we find V?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The Implementation section of that paper gets into this. See p.9-10 [here](https://www.nber.org/papers/w12831.pdf). V just has to be a symmetric and positive semidefinite matrix, but there many admissible one.